# How to specify list of individual users to have access to a particular file in Google app scripts?

Tags: javascript, private, sharing

I have a Google app script that builds a set of PDF files.  For each of these files, I want to assign a variable list of users to have access.  I don't know exactly how to do this.

The code line
doc.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW)
is my starting point.  I can replace ANYONE_WITH_LINK with PRIVATE, but then I am not sure how to specify a list of users that will have access.  Easily done interactively, but I need to do this in the script.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score -1):

Call the methods `addCommenter`, `addEditor`, and `addViewer`, as appropriate.